# On-the-fly disk encryption software with process access

Tags: encryption, on-the-fly

I'm looking for an on-the-fly disk encryption software that provides real-time disk encryption only for **one authenticated process**. I mean one process can access encrypted folder and at the same time others can't access. is there any one?

Answer (score 0):

this is a difficult problem. You want one single authenticated process to access to be able to access the encrypted disk. How do you authenticate the process? It seems that you do not trust the other processes. You will need something like a secure boot to really authenticate the process.

Another solution would be to solve this with file access rights. You use any disk encryption tool to mount an encrypted image. The single process can then be launched in the context of a privileged user (not root, create one that has rights to access the folder).

Comment: I'm going to restrict user access with OS solution, but I asked this question looking for better way. My application runs on normal windows computer and in this situation admin password may not be secure enough. I want only one process access, not for other standard or admin users.

Comment: If you do not trust your admin account you have no other way than using complete process isolation. This process has to run in kind of a virtual machine. All other solutions will not work as you do not trust your admin account.